# Trouble getting Spark aggregators to work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I am wanting to try out Aggregators in Scala Spark, but I cannot seem to get them to work using both the `select` function and the `groupBy/agg` functions (with my current implementation the `agg` function fails to compile). My aggregator is written below and should be self explanatory.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

/** Stores the number of true counts (tc) and false counts (fc) */
case class Counts(var tc: Long, var fc: Long)

/** Count the number of true and false occurances of a function */
class BooleanCounter[A](f: A => Boolean) extends Aggregator[A, Counts, Counts] with Serializable {
  // Initialize both counts to zero
  def zero: Counts = Counts(0L, 0L) 
  // Sum counts for intermediate value and new value
  def reduce(acc: Counts, other: A): Counts = { 
    if (f(other)) acc.tc += 1 else acc.fc += 1
    acc 
  }
  // Sum counts for intermediate values
  def merge(acc1: Counts, acc2: Counts): Counts = { 
    acc1.tc += acc2.tc
    acc1.fc += acc2.fc
    acc1
  }
  // Return results
  def finish(acc: Counts): Counts = acc 
  // Encoder for intermediate value type
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Counts] = Encoders.product[Counts]
  // Encoder for return type
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Counts] = Encoders.product[Counts]
}
```

Below is my test code.

```
val ds: Dataset[Employee] = Seq(
  Employee("John", 110),
  Employee("Paul", 100),
  Employee("George", 0), 
  Employee("Ringo", 80) 
).toDS()

val salaryCounter = new BooleanCounter[Employee]((r: Employee) => r.salary < 10).toColumn
// Usage works fine 
ds.select(salaryCounter).show()
// Causes an error
ds.groupBy($"name").agg(salaryCounter).show()
```

The first usage of `salaryCounter` works fine but the second results in the following compilation error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to Employee
```

Databricks has a [tutorial](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Dataset%20Aggregator.html) that is rather complicated but appears to be Spark 2.3. There is also [this](https://www.51zero.com/blog/2016/2/24/type-safety-on-spark-dataframes-part-1) older tutorial that uses an experimental feature from Spark 1.6.

Comment: How does the operation : `ds.groupBy($"name").agg(salaryCounter).show()` make sense? The output of earlier aggregation just returns a dataset with 2 columns(tc, fc) and 1 row. What is your desired output with this operation?  The UDAF when applied on `ds.groupBy($"name")` is obviously not working since the input being supplied to the UDAF in this case are not `Employee`

Comment: This would ideally produce a dataset with each row corresponding to a single name, with columns (tc, fc) for each name corresponding to the number of employees with a given name making below or above 10 monies respectively. The UDAF is not applied on `ds.groupBy($"name")` as you say, but passed to the `.agg` function. See the tutorials I linked as they have example uses that appear to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incorrectly mixing "statically typed" and "dynamically typed" APIs. To use the former version you should call `agg` on `KeyValueGroupedDataset`, not `RelationalGroupedDataset`:

```
ds.groupByKey(_.name).agg(salaryCounter)
```